# Find "youngest" superclass

Tags: java

I am looking for the best way of implementing method that would allow me to get "youngest" superclass of some class from some:

```
List<Class<?>>.
```

E.g: There is this design:

> > Skill
> >
> > > Cast
> > >
> > > > Passive
> > > >
> > > > > Active
> > > > >
> > > > > > Aura
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > OfHealing
> > > > >
> > > > > Generic
> > >
> > > Instant
> > >
> > > > Secret

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Skill>> array = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Skill>>();
array.add(Skill.class);
array.add(SkillCast.class);
array.add(SkillActive.class);
array.add(SkillAura.class);
array.add(SkillInstant.class);


public Class<? extends Skill> getYoungestParent(Class<? extends Skill> clazz, List<Class<? extends Skill>> seachIn)
{
    return ...;
}
```

Note that the array I am scanning will not always contain whole structure of inheritance represented in example. I need to find the closest relation.
I also cannot store those relations (keep registry) as system involves API and lots of reflection within.

Only thing that comes to my mind is LOTS of isAssignableFrom and isInstance, but I cannot wrap my head around as how to do it in smart way (without infinite number of if statements).

Comment: Quick sketch of the solution: for each class, call `superclass` repeatedly until you get back to `Object` and keep the results in an array or a list that starts with `Object`; then to find the lowest common superclass of two of your classes, just iterate through from the beginning of the list, while the entries are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the line of (not sure about your exact requirement)

```
public Class getYoungestParent(Class clazz, Set<Class> set)
{
    if(clazz==null) 
        return Object.class;
    if(set.contains(clazz)) 
        return clazz; 
    return getYoungestParent( clazz.getSuperclass(), set );
}
```

Comment: This is a really good solution...I just learned something by reading the docs "returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity"